# Easiest way to use client-side templates in a multi-page web application

Tags: javascript, html, templates, handlebars.js, mustache

I'm coming from a background of using frameworks like Django and Web2Py, which provide views that can do some pretty powerful inheritance.

Basically, I'm writing a multi-page webapp that consumes some JSON APIs. I'm trying to figure out the best way to achieve a cohesive layout without duplicating common content across each individual HTML page.

For example, I'd like to be able to write a `layout.html` that defines stuff like the navbar, footer, menus, etc, and then be able to write templates for each individual page that just has the stuff that's different for each page (the actual content).

The goal is to be able to serve this from any web server. I'd like to avoid a MVC framework just to handle views.

I've looked at Mustache and Handlebars a little, but haven't been able to figure out a good way to handle inheritance.

What are my options?

Comment: Handlebars has "partials", check them out: http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/handlebars-js-part-2-partials-and-helpers

Comment: Okay, that's definitely close. However, after playing with partials for a while, I'm still not sure how to structure this. How do I structure this so that I can write an HTML file that does something like "extend layout.html", and allows me to overwrite specific blocks in the layout?